# For loop is running only once

Tags: c

```
int input;
int factorial;
int half;

printf("Enter the number you wish to calculate: ");
scanf("%d", &input);    

for(x=1; x<input; x++);
{
    half = input - 1;
    factorial = input * half;
}

printf("%d\n", factorial);

return 0;
```

It's running once, giving me the input number * (input number - 1), exam, input is 5 its giving out 20. What am I doing wrong that is preventing it from continuing running?

Comment: I didn't forget to put my headers in btw, I'm using Vim and for some reason it didn't copy over.

Answer (score 6):

You have a `;` after the for-loop. Remove that and you'll be fine:

```
for(x=1; x<input; x++) {
 // your stuff
}
```

You still have to fix another error in your loop, as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You don't change `input` in your loop, so your code boils down to (for your sample input of 5):

```
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   half = 5 - 1;
   factorial = 5 * 4;
}
```

factorial 5 (`5!`) would be 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1, which should be:

```
factorial = 1;
for (i = input; i > 1; i--) {
   factorial = factorial * i;
}
```

Comment: and the semicolon is an issue

Comment: ahh, neat. Thanks! I was wondering about that, but i wasn't sure how to set 'i' to the input. What I did in my code was just me winging it. I would upvote, but I can't :(

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong?

There are many things that you are doing wrong:

- Naming a variable `half` is wrong, unless you assign a value that is truly a half of something to it
- Your loop does not use the previous value of factorial
- You always multiply `input` by `input-1`, and never change the `input`
- You do not initialize `factorial` to `1`

P.S. The fact that your loop runs empty is the least of your troubles.

P.P.S. To do it right, consider how you do it on paper: you start with `1`, and then keep multiplying the previous result by numbers from `2` to `input`. Now write the same algorithm as a C program: use `factorial` as your intermediate result, and `x` from the loop as your "current number between `1` and `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop uses the same values each time (`input` and `half`)

try

```
factorial = 1;
for(x=2; x<=input; x++)
{
    factorial *= x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually changing the state, so you should only ever get `input * (input - 1)`. Why? Well, `half` will *always* be `input - 1`, and `input` will never change. Meanwhile the value of `factorial` is simply assigned to that product *every time* you step through the loop.

I think what you intended is

```
factorial = 1;
// no sense in starting from 1, factorial already is 1
for(x = 2; 
    // using <= so as to *include* the original input value.
    x <= input; x++)
{
    // the same things a factorial = factorial * x
    factorial *= x;
}
```

BTW: You may wish to compensate for negatives too.